# How to get the string i want from split result c#

Tags: c#, split

So I get a list of data with delimiter `" "`, 
for example

```
TOTAL INVOICE          2,500,000
```

okay so it is easy if you want to print the `2,500,000` because you only need to do

```
string splittext = data.split(' ').Last();
```

but when I try it will return " ";
when I check the data, the string is like

```
string invoice = "TOTAL INVOICE      2,500,000   ";
```

it has *3 or more spaces* after the `2,500,000`

how to get the `2,500,000`? I can't use the `Last()` Method because of it.

thank you for the help

Comment: Just add `.Trim()` after .Last(); Although i would do `.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)`

Comment: Thankyou @OrelEraki my mistake i forgot about the Trim() function ..

Comment: Is it possible that input may contain currency signs? Like `TOTAL INVOICE     2,500,000 $` or `TOTAL INVOICE     2,500,000 EUR` ?

Comment: @Fildor nope , it wont contain any currency signs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should [trim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trim?view=netframework-4.8) first as this removes all leading and trailing whitespaces:

```
string splittext = data.Trim().Split(' ').Last();
```

Comment: Thankyou , it really works , i forgot about trim() @_@ thankyou again, i will accept this answer in 11 minutes xD

Answer (score 3):

You can specify `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` to get rid of *empty chunks*; another suggestion is to add `\t` as a delimiter in order to be able to process `"TOTAL INVOICE\t\t2,500,000"` (please, note *tabulations* instead of *spaces*) and alike strings:

```
 var result = data
   .Split(new char[] { ' ', '\t' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
   .Last();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have so many possibilities, here are just some of them (Not been tested)

1. Add to your current code Trim, `.Last().Trim()` - Good
2. Remove all Empty entries of splitted string. `Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)` - Better
3. Substring the text and trim the result - `myTextVariable.Substring("TOTAL INVOICE".Length).Trim()` - More efficient.